# Is the Retroblade Mount available to all characters?

Tags: wildstar

I have recently purchased Wildstar and set up the 2 Step Account Authentication.
Now I could grant my character the Retroblade Mount from the redeem window.

**Is this mount only available to one character or to all characters once they reached Level 15 as in most other games?**

[image: wildstar screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mount is available to all your characters once they reached the right level. As it is for every items you got in the account inventory, except for the Boom Boxes.